# Application Builder Map does not work for middlewares

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I am encountering the following problem:

I have a `ASP NET Core` Application where I am using the following routes:

`status`, 
`message`, 
`http`.
The first 2 accept a websocket request.

The problem is that the `AppBuilder.Map` in the pipeline does not work and it always sends me to the first route for all requests.

**Program**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)=>

        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseSockets()
        .UseUrls($"http://0.0.0.0:{Constants.SERVER_PORT}/")
        .Build();
}
```

**Startup**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddTransient<StatusService>();//(x => new StatusService());
        services.AddTransient<RegisterService>();
        services.AddTransient<MessagingService>();

        services.AddCors();

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseCors((p) => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());

        builder.UseWebSockets();

        builder.Map("/status", app =>
        {
          builder.UseMiddleware<StatusWare>();
        });
        builder.Map("/http", app =>
        {
           builder.UseMiddleware<HTTPWare>();
        });
        builder.Map("/message", app =>
        {
            builder.UseMiddleware<MessageWare>();
        });
    }
}
```

The Middlewares all use their specific service which I will not post since the `Invoke` method of the other two middlewares does not get invoked.

**Middlewares**

**Status**

```
class StatusWare
{
    StatusService handler;
    public StatusWare(StatusService _handler,RequestDelegate del)
    {
        this.handler = _handler;
        this.next = del;
    }

    RequestDelegate next;

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            await  this.next(context);
            return;
        }

        await this.handler.AddClientAsync(context.WebSockets);
    }
}
```

**Message**

```
class MessageWare
{
    private MessagingService messageService;
    private RequestDelegate next;
    public MessageWare(MessagingService serv,RequestDelegate del)
    {
        this.messageService = serv;
        this.next = del;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        await this.messageService.AcceptClientAsync(context.WebSockets);
    }
}
```

**HTTP**

```
class HTTPWare
{
    RequestDelegate next;
    RegisterService registerService;
    public HTTPWare(RequestDelegate _del,RegisterService service)
    {
        this.next = _del;
        this.registerService = service;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see the middlewares are almost identical (I did not write anything in `HttpWare` since its `Invoke` method does not get called either.

So my question is .why despite using `AppBuilder.Map` all requests go into the first middleware `StatusWare`?

Could it be because of the way the specific services are added in `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: You are using Map incorrectly, review the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-run-and-map

Comment: In the documentation its basically the same as i did.They are wrapping the `lambda` in a method and use `Run` instead of `Use`.I am using `Use` because i might need more middlewares in each branched pipeline.

Comment: It is not the same. invoking a delegate handler and configuring the middleware are totally different.

Comment: you are calling the `UseMiddleware` on the original builder and not on the delegate argument.

Comment: Ohhh i see now.So all i need to do is use the current `IAppBuilder`? depeneding on how nested i am? In my case i would use `app.UseMiddleware`  instead of `builder.UseMiddleware`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir ,you can put your solution i will upvote it.I didn't realise my error.

Comment: Yes i have tried all 3 routes.It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configure` is calling the `UseMiddleware` on the original `builder` and not on the delegate argument. In this case `app`

Update the `Map` calls to use the middleware on the builder delegate argument.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder) {
    builder.UseCors((p) => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());

    builder.UseWebSockets();

    builder.Map("/status", app => {
        app.UseMiddleware<StatusWare>();
    });
    builder.Map("/http", app => {
        app.UseMiddleware<HTTPWare>();
    });
    builder.Map("/message", app => {
        app.UseMiddleware<MessageWare>();
    });
}
```

Reference [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-run-and-map)